# Who Stole My Friends' Car?? Help!

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

Help! Last night my friends' new car was stolen!

I'm pretty sure it was one of the gangs that hang around here, and they've been a bit cocky. Where the car was parked, they spray-painted the following on the ground.

[image: I'm sometimes the last gear, and sometimes the first]

But I can't make head or tale of it, and nor can the police. Can you help?

---

So you found out who stole it, how about trying to [find *them*?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/51730/can-a-note-that-makes-no-sense-help-find-my-friends-car)

Comment: You did *not* just use Comic Sans. And JPEG artifacts too! Shocking.

Comment: [Red herring](https://www.youtube.com/user/al0z3). Now, the actual answer may be simply rotating a few of the letters to produce `ALONE`.

Comment: Nope. No rotation of letter or numbers - good idea though!

Comment: Imgur doesn't seem to give anything actually

Comment: @CalvT: Just saying, is any computer needed for the solution ?

Comment: How is that a red herring?

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil you are on the right track though, keep on

Comment: @n_palum I don't think that youtube channel with the same name has any connection with this puzzle.

Comment: @CalvT found it ;)

Comment: @Paag yes a computer is needed

Comment: Dude, where's your car, dude?

Comment: @IanMacDonald that's a follow up puzzle if my imagination works enough :)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The gang who stole your friends' car are called

> THE BAD LADZ

Thanks to @n_palum for helping in chat

---

If you

> Type it into imgur reversed (The name of the image if you click edit is 'I'm sometimes the last gear, sometimes the first' and the last gear is the gear to REVERSE [Thanks @Techidiot]) you get the following: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Z0LA.png

> [image]

Text:

> YnJvd3NlcnMud3RmL3B1enpsZS5odG1s

Using Base64 decoder (thanks @n_palum) you get the following website:

> http://browsers.wtf/puzzle.html

(The console output is 32543 [Thanks @KritixiLithos] which is the OP's user ID)

Which has

> the word 'Of'

The tab name is

> Bottom

Giving

> Bottom Of 32543

At the bottom of the OP's profile (at least at the time, may be removed in future) is a barcode

> [image: barcode]

which decodes to

> ZALD ABD ETH

which is an anagram of

> THE BAD LADZ

Comment: If you use a Base64 Decode you get this URL: browsers.wtf/puzzle.html

Comment: If it is at all relevant, the console output is `32543`

Comment: @KritixiLithos is very relevant that is the OP's user ID

Comment: This is one sophisticated gang

Comment: @EdmundReed And OP seems to be involved with them ... :D.

Comment: I do hope OP never changes their profile to invalidate this puzzle..

Comment: @WeckarE.I do intend to try and keep it there, but I asked Beastly to put it in the answer in case I accidentally remove it and loose the link

Comment: @WeckarE. added a note in the puzzle too